# INNER JOIN запрос в Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, sequelize.js

Как выполнить этот запрос в Sequelize?

```
SELECT features.name 
FROM typeFeatures
INNER JOIN features ON featuresId = features.id
```

Models:

```
const Feature = sequelize.define('feature', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false }
});

const TypeFeature = sequelize.define('typeFeature', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true }
});
```

Т.е. чтобы вместо:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "featureId": 1
}
```

Получить это:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "feature.name": "TestName"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум добавить ассоциацию между моделями:

```js
TypeFeature.belongsTo(Feature, { foreignKey: 'featuresId' })
```

А потом сделать запрос `TypeFeature` и включить заассоциированную модель
`Feature` (см. [запросы с ассоциациями](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#basics-of-queries-involving-associations)):

```js
const typefeature = await TypeFeature.findByPk(1, {
  include: [{
    model: Feature,
    attributes: ['name']
  }]
})
```

Тогда в `typefeature` будет:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "feature": {
      "name": "TestName"
    }
}
```

Если прям надо без вложенного объекта просто на уровне полей основной модели получить `name`, то так:

```js
const typefeature = await TypeFeature.findByPk(1, {
  attributes: ['id', [['feature', 'name'], 'feature.name']],
  include: [{
    model: Feature,
    attributes: []
  }]
})
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение